# Variable Scope Behavior in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, function, global-variables, eval

I have the following two small scripts:

Script 1:

```
eval("local = 3;");
console.log(typeof local);
Function("console.log(typeof local);")();
```

Output:

```
number
number
```

Script 2:

```
eval("var local = 3;");
console.log(typeof local);
Function("console.log(typeof local);")();
```

Output:

```
number
undefined
```

What gives? Should eval put local in the global namespace regardless of whether or not the string passed has a `var local = 3` or a `local = 3`? If that is the case, shouldn't `Function(...)` find that the type of local is number in the second case and not undefined?

**EDIT 1:**

I ran both scripts in JSFiddle and those were the results I got. However, when I run them outside JSFiddle, the expected results occurs where both outputs are:

```
number 
number
```

Comment: You're not executing Script 2 in the global scope, so `eval` is creating a local variable.

Comment: It is in global scope. But it was in JSFiddle, not running straight from browser.

Comment: See my comment below, jsfiddle defaults the local scope of a window.onload handler.

Comment: Can you add comment as an edit to your answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function):

> Functions created with the `Function` constructor do not create closures to their creation contexts; they always run in the window context (unless the function body starts with a "use strict"; statement, in which case the context is undefined).

In terms of the spec, this is because of Step 11 from [15.3.2.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.2.1) (emphasis mine):

> Return a new Function object created as specified in 13.2 passing P as the FormalParameterListopt and body as the FunctionBody. **Pass in the Global Environment as the Scope parameter** and strict as the Strict flag.

So your Script 2 creates a variable in the local scope ([which I'm assuming is not global](http://jsfiddle.net/8kG5U/), or the output would be different<sup>1</sup>), and the `console.log` eval'd by `Function` cannot see it.

---

<sup>1</sup> As your comments confirm, you were running your tests in jsfiddle, which by default wraps your code in a window.onload handler, forcing you out of global scope.

Comment: I was in global scope but I was using JSFiddle. Seems weird happens in JSFiddle as opposed to running the script straight through the browser.

Comment: JSFiddle defaults to a window.onload handler with your code inside. See the fiddle I just linked, which has the right settings: http://jsfiddle.net/8kG5U/

Comment: Oh... didn't notice that. Thanks.

Comment: @moesef: It often helps to read the documentation: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#fiddle-settings-sidebar.